# RSpatial: Convert a grid (list) to a raster using terra

Tags: list, grid, raster, terra

To build a raster from a grid in list format I use the raster pckg:

```
# building a grid
grd <- list(x = (1:10), y = (1:10), z = matrix(1:100, 10, 10))
class(grd)
[1] "list"

# grid to RasterLayer
r = raster(grd)
r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 10.5, 0.5, 10.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

Very simple. However, as the raster package is being replaced by terra, I want to adapt my scripts, but with terra I can't find an easy way to convert the grid to SpatRaster. Has anyone found solutions to this?

I have tried `rast()` but it doesn´t work

```
r2 = rast(grd)
```

> Error: [rast,list] none of the elements of x are a SpatRaster

The solution cannot be to change the way the grid is created because this is a simplified example. The lists are more complex, they come out in that format after going through an interpolation function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With terra version 1.7-72 (currently the development version) you can do

```
x <- terra::rast(grd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, updating to version 1.7.72 solved my problem. Best regards

Comment: Robert, I now see that you are one of the developers. Thank you very much for the excellent work you do. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use proper method (see `?terra::rast()` and `matrix-method` for details)

```r
grd <- list(x = (1:10), y = (1:10), z = matrix(1:100, 10, 10))
raster::raster(grd)
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0.5, 10.5, 0.5, 10.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 1, 100  (min, max)


terra::rast(grd[[3]], crs = "EPSG:4326")
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   :     1 
#> max value   :   100
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-06 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This method does not capture the extent correctly (it is close in this case because the example uses `1:10`)

Comment: But extent can be provided as a `terra::rast(matrix, extent = )` parameter? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, that can be done; but you would need to figure out the extent.

Comment: C'man.. That's the point. If I had to replace one solution with another, I would make sure that the second one had all the necessary data to work.. A bit philosophical and off topic: Robert, I really appreciate what you do and how you develop the package. I'm using it almost every day. Hats off, really. But users should also be required to understand the changes/consequences of their choices.

Comment: `grd` uses a legacy format for grid data in R.  I think it makes sense to coerce it automatically and correctly.

Comment: Thank you both. First of all, I apologize if my question seemed like a complaint; it was not my intention at all, I thank and congratulate the developers of terra because it's an amazing tool. Robert, following your suggestion, I updated to version 1.7.72 of, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.